# cout is not working inside switch statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, cout

Good day,

I have a loop that computes values and displays the output to the console. However, when I run the code, `cout <<` does not display the output I expected. In fact, it doesn't display any output. The only way I know the code even works is that the values are changing.

`cout <<` was working just fine until I used the switch statement. Every piece of text that I expected to print to the console inside the statement and the loop was just dead text. It didn't work. I also tried flushing the stream using `cout.flush`. That did not work either I cannot include all of my code, but here are the problem lines:

```cpp
if (exampleloop == '1'){
  ExampleValue = (ExampleValue - 1);
  ExampleValue = (ExampleValue - ExampleValue);
  cout << "ExampleText " << ExampleValue << " ExampleText";

  if (ExampleValue <= 0){
    cout << "ExampleText.";
  }

  if (ExampleValue <= 0){
    cout << ExampleText";
  }

  example_label:
  ExampleValue = (ExampleValue1 - ExampleValue1);
  cout << "ExampleText! " << ExampleValue! << " ExampleText!";
  goto Example_label;
}
```

And the only way I know that the code is being computed

```cpp
cout << "EXAMPLE TEXT  ExampleValue1 at "<< ExampleValue <<" . ExampleText";
```

In this case, "Example Text" would never appear on the console. However, the "Example Values" would be computed and the changes would reflect on the code above.

My IDE is repl.it

Is this my fault, or my IDE's? And what is going on?

(Yes, I `#include iostream` and I'm `using namespace std`)

Comment: Sorry, it's your fault, I'm 99% sure of it

Comment: Impossible to say what is going on from the code posted (which wouldn't even compile as there are mismatched quotes).

Comment: You should post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @John Let's say the quotes are't mismatched. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Razorshnegax018: devil's in the details. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Razorshnegax018 No I don't. I'm pretty sure you're wrong about 'here is where the problem lies' though. What you're showing is simply the code that you say isn't working. There's absolutely no reason to think that's where the bug is though. C++ is rarely that simple.

Comment: Actually @John I took some advice from the minimal reproducible example links, and found out that the problem was a conio.h header that I downloaded from GitHub. The clrscr() command clears the screen, but that was the reason why I couldn't print output from statements and loops. Thank you, and you can close this question

Comment: @Razorshnegax018 Glad you fixed the problem (and super glad you took the time to read the links). Easiest thing to do is for you to delete the question. As the author you are allowed to do that.